# Question about thread-safety and disabling multi-threading with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, thread-safety, puma, application-server

[The Puma readme](https://github.com/puma/puma) states the following: "Be aware that additionally Puma creates threads on its own for internal purposes (e.g. handling slow clients). So, even if you specify -t 1:1, expect around 7 threads created in your application."

Suppose that my Rails app is not thread-safe, and as such I need to prevent the app from being multi-threaded. Let's say I use Puma and specify -t 1:1 to try configure this. Is there any thread-safety-related reason for me to be concerned that Puma will still create threads on its own for internal purposes? I think the answer is probably no, but I'm asking here to be sure.

I asked this same question in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2910) as well.

Comment: I don't think so. Then the thread safety issue would be at Rails or Puma level. It seems it has happened in the past (see Evan Phoenix PR mentionnef here: https://bearmetal.eu/theden/how-do-i-know-whether-my-rails-app-is-thread-safe-or-not/ ) but I doubt this is still the case. Though while reading the aforementioned thread I realized my current app mais not be threadsafe. The more you read about it, the more you realize you have not covered everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub issue received the following answer and was marked as completed:

> No, these threads don't interact with your app in any way, and only one thread will ever run your application code, ever, with no concurrency.